# Using Xcode for embedded C development. No cmd-click on functions

Tags: c, xcode, embedded

I do a bit of iOS development and a bit of embedded C development for an ARM Cortex M0 micro. My build system for the embedded stuff is all in make and I use the gcc toolchain.

To my surprise, in Xcode 7.0 I can start a new Xcode project, use the "Other" -> "External Build System" template, add all my sources including my Makefile and have the code build just fine. Xcode calls out to /usr/bin/make and all is well. So far so good.

The minute I cmd-click on a function call, however, I don't go anywhere. I get an error beep and a question mark overlay.

How do I get Xcode educated about my symbol table so I can click around?

Comment: Not sure about XCode, but in Visual Studio to enable the code navigations and auto-completeion features, you have to add all the source files to the project and set all command line macros and include search paths to match your external build.  That way the IDE can parse the files - it can't do that without all that information, but remember that none of these settings affect the actual build and have to be maintained in sync manually.